# Serializability in database management systems

Tags: database, serializable

If a schedule is serializable I.e. it's output is equal to that of a serial schedule I.e it maintains the ACID properties of a database, then why do we use concurrency control schemes on them (locks, timestamp based protocols)? What do we do if a schedule is not serializable?

Comment: Is it possible that you misunderstood the term `serializable`?